# Flutter: OnChange event for TextFormField field

Tags: flutter

I have a text form field (zip code). When the user complete entering the value. I would like call an Api and populate the city and state field on the form.

How do I know when the user finish entering the zip?

Here my current code for the zip code field

```
    TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Palette.GREY),
      initialValue: (addresses != null) ?   addresses[0].postalCode : ''

      validator: (val) => validateZipCode(val),
      onSaved: (val) => {
          onSaved(val),
       },
   ),
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could check the input on-the-fly by using onChanged:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text) {
    print("First text field: $text");
  },
);
```

The function is called any time the user enters something to the text field.

Check after every entry for a valid zip code, e.g. US and CA with a regular expression, such as:

```
^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))$
```

(taken from https://regex101.com/library/xH5sD3)

If the zip code is valid, populate the city field.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `validator` to make calls to your API functions before it returns the null value ( zip is correct) , to populate the fields:

```
String validateZipCode(String value) {

    if(value.length == 6){
      setStateNameByZip(value); // replace them with calls to your API
      setCityNameByZip(value);
      return null ;
    }

    return 'incorrect zip' ;

}
```